# Necessarily Splits?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space

The result below appears in the following article: On globally generated vector bundles on projective space.

> Lemma 3. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a globally generated vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ and let $\mathcal{E}^{*}$ denotes its dual bundle. If $h^{0}(\mathcal{E}^{*}) = r$, then there exists a globally generated vector bundle $\mathcal{E}^{'}$ such that $\mathcal{E} \cong \mathcal{E}^{'} \oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{\oplus r}$ and $h^{0}(\mathcal{E}^{'}) = 0$.

In the demonstration  of this result, the author says that:

Since  $\mathcal{E}$is globally generated we have a surjection $$H^{0}(\mathcal{E}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}} \longrightarrow \mathcal{E} \longrightarrow 0.$$

Since $h^{0}(\mathcal{E}^{*}) = r$, we have a surjection $$\mathcal{E} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{r} \longrightarrow 0.$$

He claims that the composition $$H^{0}(\mathcal{E}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{r} \longrightarrow 0,$$ necessarily splits, whence $$\mathcal{E} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{r} \longrightarrow 0.$$ also splits. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Small typo: in the statement of the proposition, you have $\mathcal O$ taken to a tensor power when you want a direct sum power.

Comment: I looked up the paper from which the lemma is taken, and as far as I can tell the only point not repeated in this paper is that the composition is nonzero and THAT is what makes it split. I think being nonzero just follows from being a composition of surjections, and the reason it then splits is because it's just a morphism of trivial bundles so given globally by a matrix of functions hence a matrix of numbers, so you can basically "split off an $r\times r$ submatrix of maximal rank and then invert it."

Comment: @TabesBridges. First: Thank you for watching for the typo. Second:  According to the Okonek book, if I call K the kernel  of the compostion, then I must show that: $$\text{Ext}^{1}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{\oplus r} ,  K) =  H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^{n}, (\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{\oplus r} )^{*} \oplus K) = 0.$$  Right?

Comment: I am trying to do this. If I'm wrong, please let me know. I will study your suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure that's necessary but yes, vanishing of the appropriate Ext group would do the trick. One more typo in your comment I think: shouldn't the sheaf of which you are taking $H^1$ be the tensor product $(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}^r)^* \otimes K$, not their direct sum?

Comment: @TabesBridges. Yes, it is the  tensor product. Sorry.